# Raster and vector analysis for profile extraction in Python

Tags: python, raster, dem, vector, shapely

I have quite complex problem and I have two options to solve it. For a multiline shapefile (river) I would like to get cross profiles and extract DEM values for the lines.

I was thinking 1: Create orthogonal lines at defined step:

#Define a shp for the output features. Add a new field called 'M100' where the z-value of the line is stored to uniquely identify each profile...

```
layerOut = outShp.CreateLayer('line_utm_neu_perp', layerRef, osgeo.ogr.wkbLineString)
layerDefn = layerOut.GetLayerDefn() # gets parameters of the current shapefile
layerOut.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('M100', ogr.OFTReal))

# Calculate the number of profiles/perpendicular lines to generate
n_prof = int(geomIn.Length()/spc)

# Define rotation vectors
rot_anti = np.array([[0, -1], [1, 0]])
rot_clock = np.array([[0, 1], [-1, 0]])
    
# Start iterating along the line
for prof in range(1, n_prof):
    # Get the start, mid and end points for this segment
    seg_st = geomIn.GetPoint(prof-1) # (x, y, z)
    seg_mid = geomIn.GetPoint(prof)
    seg_end = geomIn.GetPoint(prof+1)
    
    # Get a displacement vector for this segment
    vec = np.array([[seg_end[0] - seg_st[0],], [seg_end[1] - seg_st[1],]])    

    # Rotate the vector 90 deg clockwise and 90 deg counter clockwise
    vec_anti = np.dot(rot_anti, vec)
    vec_clock = np.dot(rot_clock, vec)

    # Normalise the perpendicular vectors
    len_anti = ((vec_anti**2).sum())**0.5
    vec_anti = vec_anti/len_anti
    len_clock = ((vec_clock**2).sum())**0.5
    vec_clock = vec_clock/len_clock

    # Scale them up to the profile length
    vec_anti = vec_anti*sect_len
    vec_clock = vec_clock*sect_len

    # Calculate displacements from midpoint
    prof_st = (seg_mid[0] + float(vec_anti[0]), seg_mid[1] + float(vec_anti[1]))
    prof_end = (seg_mid[0] + float(vec_clock[0]), seg_mid[1] + float(vec_clock[1]))

    # Write to output
    geomLine = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
    geomLine.AddPoint(prof_st[0],prof_st[1])
    geomLine.AddPoint(prof_end[0],prof_end[1])
    featureLine = ogr.Feature(layerDefn)
    featureLine.SetGeometry(geomLine)
    featureLine.SetFID(prof)
    featureLine.SetField('M100',round(seg_mid[2],1))
    layerOut.CreateFeature(featureLine)
```

Problem here is that it works on one line only and not on multiline. Also, I believe there could be more elegant way...

2nd option could be creating parallel lines with offset and extract values at the same distance from the start. But I tried it only once and it did not work on my objects.

`z = shapefile.offset_curve(10.0,'left')`

But here I do not know what object to pass in order to make it work. Also I was thinking about creating buffer and extracting values of raster.

PS. Since I would like to deploy this into separate research and app, QGIS or ArcGIS is not an option. There are definitely tools which I will use for check

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As anew user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question.  We are a *problem-solving* site, in which discussion-oriented compound questions are likely to be closed as off-topic. Please [Edit] your Question to focus on a single approach and ask a single question.